# how to view assigned to info in the assignee's doc library

Tags: 2010, content

Can you please point me in the right direction to be able to do the following:

The scenario is as follows: I have SP2010 Doc Library named Doc IQ with subfolders and documents. I have added the **Assigned To** field to all of the folders and documents.

Now the  client wants the items against their **Assigned To** name show in their own document library in the same site collection.

How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Charming,

You can create a View and set it as default... Inside the view in Filter section, select Assigned To field and in Value write `[Me]`

See Below:

[Step 1: Click create view in List Settings]
[image]

[Step 2: Give name and check make default]
[image]

[Step 3: Filter]
[image]

[Step 4: You can see all views]
[image]

[Me] means the user currently logged in

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I have the DocIQ folder that contains all other folders with documents in them ASSIGNED TO: various people AND THEN i have Doc libaries for each of the ASSIGNED TO: people under TEAM FOLDERS on the same site. The documents from DOCIQ needs to appear against each ASSIGNEE's document folder in view format. Is this possible or do i have to use Content type Routing?